# how to show preview and calculate width and height of .psd file using Java

Tags: java, image, swing, photoshop

We are developing a desktop application using Java Swing that requires to show width and height of the selected .psd file. Also it needs to show the preview of the .psd file. Is it possible to do it in Java? If so how this can be done? Any help is appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [java-psd-library](http://code.google.com/p/java-psd-library/) does what you need.

```
try {
  FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("image.psd");
  PsdImage psdFile = new PsdImage(stream);
  System.out.println("Image width: " + psdFile.getWidth());
  System.out.println("Image height: " + psdFile.getHeight());
  PsdView view = new PsdView();
  view.setPsdFile(psdFile);
  getContentPane().add(view);
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println("Error reading image file image.psd: " + e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [PSDReader](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/DecodesaPhotoShoppsdfileintooneormoreframes.htm) ;)